# Create .txt file from excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to export some data from an excel sheet to a .txt file, however it needs to be in exactly the same format - basically if my excel shows:

```
   A  B  C  D
1     X  X  X
2  X  X  X  X
3  X  X  X  X
4  X  X  X  X
```

Then I need the text file to show the below with no commas

```
    X  X  X
 X  X  X  X
 X  X  X  X
 X  X  X  X
```

I have the code below and it was previously working but now when I run it no .txt file is generated and I get no error, I can see it creating/closing the wb.

```
Sub EventToV3D()
'Sub which exports final events to .txt file allowing V3D pipeline to be used
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim saveFile As String
Dim WorkRng As Range


'LON
Set WorkRng = Worksheets("LON_OUT").Range("A1:F12")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Add
WorkRng.Copy
wb.Worksheets(1).Paste
saveFile = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "LON"
wb.SaveAs FileName:=saveFile, FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
wb.Close
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Try keeping `Application.DisplayAlerts` on `True` and check whether you get any message boxes that point you to the source of the problem.

Comment: (...and `ScreenUpdating` as well, or you might not see the message box.)

Comment: NOTE: When exporting to "CSV" you can use any delimiter you want, including spaces or tabs.

Answer (score 0):

After you call `Application.Workbooks.Add` the new workbook is active, and `Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path` is empty (because an unsaved workbook has no path).
So your workbook is getting saved, but likely not where you think (will go to whatever is the Current Directory).  If you want the path to the workbook running the code then use `ThisWorkbook.Path`.

`Path` also doesn't include an ending "", so if LON is a folder then you will need to add the "" before that.